# Use .format() and fstring at the same time

Tags: python, variables, f-string

I have a string with a variable that I want to define at a certain moment of the program, and others that will be defined later on. I need to define the former in the f'string fashion, and the latter in the .format() fashion. Here's a fake example:

```
name = 'George'

greeting = f'Hello, {name}. The current time is {}, so you should say good {}'

print(greeting.format('10AM','morning')) # Hello, George. The current time is 10AM, so you should say good morning'
```

Of course this doesn't work. But how could I handle situations like these? Because in the actual program, the second and third variables are defined by a class over which I don't have any control (it's a Q&A flow with Langchain).

Answer (score 0):

use double curly brackets like this:

```py
name = 'George'
greeting = f'Hello, {name}. The current time is {{}}, so you should say good {{}}'
print(greeting.format('10AM','morning'))
```

Comment: As a side note, not sure if this behaviour will change with new f-string stuff coming in with Python 3.12 but  works fine atm..